# For which fractions is it standard practice to specify using 'over' instead of '-ths'?

Tags: word-usage, fractions

For which fractions is it standard practice to specify using 'over' instead of ordinals?

For example, we read 5/16 as 'five-sixteenths' but 100/151 as 'one hundred over one hundred fifty one'.

Where do we stop reading numbers like that, and start using 'over'?

Comment: As far as I know we haven't stopped reading it like that. 'Over' might be used when teaching children about fractions.

Comment: 'One thousand three hundred and seventy-three two thousand five hundred and sixty-sevenths' admittedly sounds a non-starter.  As a number we'd ever meet, never mind a speech impediment. Have you ever encountered a case where anything over twentieths is used? Perhaps fiftieths, hundredths, thousandths, millionths.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My many sets of Allen wrenches  and ratchet sockets go to 64th...for when I am working on American vehicles.

Comment: You might say 'five-hundredths' for measurements, if for some reason you didn't want to say 'five thou'.

Comment: One hundred one hundred and fifty .... what?  Fiftyoneths??

Answer (score 2):

There no sharp switch. I suggest, from experience compatible with the comments, that the transition is essentially complete by x/101, with some use below this and some exceptions.

Commonly-used fractions below x/100 almost always use the form similar to the ordinal numbers (e.g. inverse powers of two: x/64 would be *x 64ths*).  I suspect that they are common because they're used in measurements, such as distances in inches. Uncommon denominators may use either as they approach 100.

I propose two reasons that work together: it starts getting harder to be clear, and some combinations don't work. "Two hundred and seventy-fifths" presumably means 2/175 but relies on hearing the *s* clearly after the *fth*. It could also be parsed as x/275 for unspecified plural x. A clumsy partial solution is "two *one*-hundred and seventy-fifths". Denominators ending with a 1 (except 11) don't help - even *one twenty-first* is less intuitive than surrounding numbers.

The biggest exceptions are major powers of ten, such as *thousandths* and *millionths*, followed by many of the hundredths ("one five-hundredth"). I've certainly heard *one ten-thousandth* used (I'd probably use *one part in ten thousand*, rather than "... over...", but that may say something about the context in which I use such fraction). These again are common, but for comparing magnitudes.

From experience, the major binary powers (after 64) don't work like the powers of ten. I supervise an experiment in which the smallest measurable signal is 3.3V/1024, and I know if I refer to "thousand-and-twenty-fourths" I'll only confuse people.

So you can't write a rule, you can only really try to capture what people use in practice,  and this won't be universal.